# rspec let, how to unset a property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following specs:

```
describe Country do

  let (:country) { Country.new(:country_code => "NL", :name => "Netherlands") }

  context "when country code is empty" do
  let (:country) { Country.new(:name => "Netherlands") }

    it "should not be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_falsey
    end
    it "should not save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_falsey
    end    
  end

  context "when country code is not empty" do
    let (:country) { Country.new(:country_code => "NL") }

    it "should be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_truthy
    end

    it "should save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_truthy
    end
  end

  context "when name is empty" do
    it "should not be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_falsey
    end

    it "should not save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_falsey
    end
  end


end


end
```

What I would like to achieve is to 'unset' a property in the let method. Ideally I would like to:

`let (:country) { country.country_code = nil }`

I would like to do this because I want to test for the presence (and NON presence) of a SINGLE property of `Country` while at the same time keeping the other properties set.

Comment: why you want to do it in the `let()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. You can use a `#before` inside each context:

   `before do
      country.code = nil #change this in another context to a non-empty code
   end`
2. Or, you could change your top-level let to refer to a country_code `let`, like this:

   `let (:country) { Country.new(:country_code => country_code, :name => "Netherlands") }`

   `#immediately after  context "when country code is empty"
    let(:country_code) { nil }`

   `.....`
   `#immediately after: context "when country code is not empty" do
    let (:country_code) { "NL" }`

   If your `context "when name is empty` requires a `country_code`, then define a top level code as a default.

Therefore, your code could look like this:

```
  describe Country do

  let (:country) { Country.new(:country_code => country_code, :name => "Netherlands") }
  let(:country_code) { "NL" } #default

  context "when country code is empty" do
    let (:country_code) { nil } 

    it "should not be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_falsey
    end
    it "should not save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_falsey
    end    
  end

  context "when country code is not empty" do
    let (:country_code) {  "NL" }

    it "should be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_truthy
    end

    it "should save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_truthy
    end
  end

  context "when name is empty" do
    it "should not be valid" do
      expect(country.valid?).to be_falsey
    end

    it "should not save" do
      expect(country.save).to be_falsey
    end
  end


end


end
```

Comment: I have gone for the `before` solution

Answer (score 3):

For the specific action that should be executed before any of `it`, you have to use the [`before` hook](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) block, with passed `:all` key to the method. It allows to prepare tests for the context block once:

```
describe "when country code is not empty" do
   before(:all) { country.country_code = nil }
   # ...
end
```

**NOTE** I've used `describe` keyword against `context`. But:

> According to the rspec source code, “context” is just a alias method of “describe” ...
>
> The purpose of “describe” is to wrap a set of tests against one functionality while “context” is to wrap a set of tests against one functionality under the same state.

More info in `describe` versus `context` you can read in the article: [Describe vs. Context in RSpec](http://lmws.net/describe-vs-context-in-rspec).

Also you can use [`before` context](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-%60before(:context)%60-block-in-example-group) block:

```
before(:context) { country.country_code = nil }

context "when country code is not empty" do
   # ...
end
```

Comment: I would use context here. It is the perfect example of when to use context over describe. You are not describing a piece of functionality but the context of some tests. You cold wrap the tests for #valid? and #save in describe blocks.